# apache displaying some really strange characters

Tags: php, apache, drupal, encoding, debian

I have an Apache web server with several websites on it. All websites are OK except for one...

On one specific Drupal website, I have a really strange issue when I browse the site, it displays the following :

```
����r�Ȳ(�܎X��fǴ������I�mٲ-K����`�"  `\(ɽ{�|�|����9�{"&⼟����/�̪P�P$e�zO{�ɺfee��*+�ޣ��>�uG�{�ޣ��s㞢<�А(Ƙ� �+Q8T{�� �Ц~�8�3Z}b�k���!�TF�kk"S    �. ,�P?MQ�'
?� �4�&�(��z��F؋O��d]f �th��pl��2rM2Py#���#��o� ��sl=��'H����ϑ5]�l�NH�P=:�hE1���JH��b
�a�B�AP�ȶ�ŧ�z �C# �V��O��l�A�����]�*���6ΫC�AO�i�� iP�5@�D
�9$Sl� *J��W�   ���1������U�-��F��  4i`��Z��IJU�������S�7��H*/?��~��T��y�V�ʪ@����?��ǝAױb/����W��pQ:���dC� �����;z�35�A˨��ͪf���
�2��D�-�*��K�nFD-�0�����`ߔ��dB���ů�l�A +�M7_l�,���ܦ������ЂV�Y�o��
���E^���_�t��ዝ`�]?<|��s:98�9G�W��*eBM���۶D�7�;����ы��_�ó^�� ·������v��S#��Y������f^� �:�r���Ux��z>1�}i��'�_��c�����5�b
=;���a�ٸ(��{~y����P?[������}���������x�ۇ�|� x�G=���r^？8���řGφ�`�?w��Oɇ�������m�m9���R)(�����
���~�}�������n`�?k�~ l���z�y��/Uw�Н���d仑c>�Ic�����Ty����O�G7�/��a���?�iؠ�O�њ�BA������������?k0�
{�jl�7?a�_=~z�7�����S������19�p�M��|��W���ӝޯ��f�wk�ء���ԵO7?����;/���/�
�@�?{�}�o_?��`=����ɻ9�+�j���n}�g<}�}qf�խ���k՚�����>D[��|�b�K�i�`<�r�<�P���-
```

I have nothing else than a page full of those special characters...

Does anybody already encountered this kind of issue ?

I spent half of the day on it, so I would love to hear any idea from you guys.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What DB encoding did you use for your database on that site?

Comment: does this accour while requesting a .txt-file? html-file? image-file? is it always the same result or even the same Content? any log-files from Apache?

Comment: @PanamaJack : DB encoding is utf8_general_ci (InnoDB), same encoding for the other websites.

Comment: @mech : it occurs when requesting php files and no it's not always the same content, if I refresh the page I get another set of random characters. sadly no logs from apache, even with log level "warn"

Comment: and if you are requesting an Image for example the result will be fine? in this case i would guess that something is wrong with the cgi-Setting or something around it? can't help any further because i use IIS, but hope, that this Information will help others to resolve your problem

Comment: @mech : if I upload an image, and browse it, it displays correctly, same for a txt file. What do you mean by "Cgi-settings" ? Anyway thanks for the advices

Comment: as far as i know, php works in Apache as a cgi-module. thats something like: hey Apache, i would like to have that php-file, Apache knows "oh, i have to pass it through the php-Parser bevor i can deliver it", so Apache passes it to php, php pareses and delivers the result back to Apache, now Apache will deliver the result to the requesting brwoser

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

In Drupal settings, in the performances section, I had "Compress cached pages." checked.

If I uncheck it, it works...

I don't really understand why, but maybe I had two level of compression or something like this.